# how to install adnet 802.11n wifi adapter driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, adapter, helpfile

i am a new user in ubuntu and i am unable to install my wifi adapter driver i.e of adnet 802.11n please help i had uninstalled my previous windows os

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Insert the device and run this terminal command: `lsusb`. Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

First check your USB configuration by typing `lsusb` in your terminal and check it.. see the image for more info..

[image: 1]

If your USB configuration is this **0bda:f179** Then you can try this following commands...

## install :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)    
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu    
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu    
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0    
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0    
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

## Run following commands for disable power management and plugging/replugging issues:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/modprobe.d/    
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
echo "options rtl8188fu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
```

## How to uninstall :

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8188fu/1.0 --all    
sudo rm -f /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8188fufw.bin   
sudo rm -f /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
```

Comment: Please be aware that installing the wrong driver can rise future compatibility issues with OP devices. Providing a more general answer would be preferred, as well as waiting for OP to provide more information about their hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shorter version from the [GitHub link](https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu) given in the detailed answer by @Vashishth Patel that worked for me is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8188fu-dkms
```